# Direct mp3 access from ipod

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, mp3

How to get direct access to mp3 file from ipod? I need to receive signal amplitude, as a function of time?

Edit

Actually I need to detect music beats, so if you can offer some libs (on c, c++, objective-c) (with free commercial using) for doing that, will be perfect.
Or some libs just for getting direct access to mp3 file.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you plan to connect to the ipod? Via link-in or via usb?

Comment: @Lagerbaer: I am writing program for ipod. I need just enter to the custom music.